# Adding properties to objects which are already stored in localStorage

Tags: html, object, properties, local-storage

I have an object in localStorage, something like:

{"one":"oneone","two":"twotwo"}

You get the picture.

For some reason attempting to add more items to the object won't work. If I want to add "three":"threethree", it ignores that and when I update the storage area in Opera Dragonfly it shows the same old object, unchanged...

Does anybody know how to append to objects on the fly? Or will I have to append to a copy of the object in my code, then clear the old object from localStorage, and store the updated one? I can see this being the only way, but it seems like it might be a bit ugly... Ideas please! :D

Comment: It is a string so you can not add props.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the safest and cleanest way to do this is getting the object from localStorage, parsing it, add some data ans stringify it for storing.

Like you say, it is a bit ugly, but you can create a function to do this

```
function mergeLocalStorage(key, obj){
    var newObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
    for (var k in obj){
        newObj[k] = obj[k];
    }
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(newObj));
    return newObj;
}
```